# How to solve $f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-1) f(n-2)$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

Consider the following recurrence:

$$f(0) = f(1) = 2$$
$$f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-1) f(n-2)$$

It is clear the function grows very quickly but how can it be solved exactly? If this is difficult, I would be happy with an asymptotic or $\Theta()$ answer.

Comment: Are you going to delete this question too?

Comment: @TheHolyJoker It was shown to be a duplicate. Should I have left it nonetheless?

Comment: I thought the other question was not an exact solution, maybe I was wrong, nevermind

Comment: An exact solution seems difficult, but numerically we seem to have $f(n) \sim C^{\phi^n}$, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio and $C \approx 2.019856831442518$.

Comment: @GregMartin Wow, that’s a function that grows faster than I thought.  How did you compute it?

Comment: I think since it's an asymptotic result, he left out the extra $f(n-1)$ term and solved $f(n)=f(n-1)f(n-2)$.

Comment: I would be happy with an asymptotic result if an exact one is too difficult.

Comment: Do you know how to solve the easier product case?

Comment: @Anush: I simply compted the first 35 terms (using Mathematica) and did some linear fitting to various logarithms of the data.

Comment: @Luke: without the extra $f(n-1)$ term, the closed form is easily seen to be $f(n) = 2^{F_n}$ where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number. That grows like $(2^{1/\sqrt5})^{\phi^n}$, while the OP's sequence really does seem to have that mysterious constant instead of $2$ in its rate of growth.

Comment: PS: the constant $2.019856831442518$ looks suspiciously like $\frac{40}{27} 2^{1/\sqrt5}$.

Comment: Interesting, how did you arrive at that approximation?

Comment: @TheHolyJoker See [Should I delete my question if I find out that it's a duplicate or near duplicate?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25726/272831).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $f(n-1)$ term is fairly insignificant compared to the $f(n-1)f(n-2)$ term. That is, consider the following:

$$g(n)=g(n-1)g(n-2)$$

Letting $g=2^h$ we get

$$h(n)=h(n-1)+h(n-2)$$

and hence $h(n)=F_{n+1}$, where $F_n$ is the nth Fibonacci number. Hence we get the asymptotic:

$$f(n)\simeq2^{F_{n+1}}\simeq2^{\phi^{n+1}/\sqrt5}$$

where $\phi$ is the golden ratio.

We can more accurately see how the provided sequences compares to something like $2^{\phi^{n+C}}$ by extracting $C$ from

$$C=\lim_{n\to\infty}\log_\phi(\log_2(f(n)))-n$$

This converges very quickly to $C\simeq-0.9705900452306$.

$$f(n)\simeq2^{\phi^{n-0.9705900452306}}$$

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDLDoIwELz3KzZwoSqlVBvjwRNn/8ALPiHRUrEmJYRvx5VCfKftYWemM5Mtb5uq1VkOSwji8So1GbteShNISiNBTsXRcR2BU4AjJQkiIWeLOZcLzmdSTLmctxbRCp9gnBB9M1fw9jbdmnV3Uq3Lwubn1OSF8gaBXw/OIqho46R@jSmjEfZJaOP9UNpPpXBKcihKUJArmDIWSwJgJ10l@zCr6AQsYnh96H3grRYyf8KGIOWCepPk67uvn6t6taCRW2WoyF7t2vYO)

The values quickly grow too large for floats. It may be better take a look at the logarithm of the terms:

\begin{align}\log_2(f(n))&=\log_2(f(n-1))+\log_2(f(n-2)+1)\\&=\log_2(f(n-1))+\log_2(f(n-2))+\log_2\left(1+\frac1{f(n-2)}\right)\\&\simeq\log_2(f(n-1))+\log_2(f(n-2))+\frac1{\ln(2)f(n-2)}\end{align}

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBBTsMwEEX3PsUo2dhOm4wdjOMFq6y5QTcBWhqpOCZ1JVtVzx5MUyAIZG/mvxn9PzOenuLk9j08ABXFY@f35fF99FQxVklyGF5ndgWpoqlk5GDlUpOMtKleY2k0KoN4p2SNSk9hBXHRKKmUojaybpRGUxsska0WVMtGaIHiUyfEnfwRsm3onv3m@jrnxiH0b53vB5t9NeTneNn4/JyCcU6bomWX7BuFBTIzIrthBAu9heRT3iMBuMUMRSxERdNyXHIeU7SQYPo5BPhlnrT/HOzscJtp/8zk7udmgVXzcdeWbO3LNH0A)